# selecting date in specific format from mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to get a date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format from mysql which has a field type timestamp. [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) suggest to use Date(field_name). however `achieved the result as` wanted in `phpMyAdmin`. The selected view shows Date in the format I wanted. but when I try it from sails using sails-mysql adapter its giving time and zone also.

that is when I run query `SELECT Date(field) FROM mytable` I get the following results.

1. for phpMyAdmin the result was **"2016-10-22"**
2. for sails query the response was **"2016-10-21T18:30:00.000Z"**

the value stored in table is: **"2016-10-22 12:31:39"**

what is the reason behind sails and phpMyAdmin gives different responses for the same queries. Is there anything else to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mysql date format function like this

```
 select DATE_FORMAT(your_date,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

it will five you the exact format

Comment: it worked but i'm still confused why Date() was working in phpMyAdmin and not in sails?